# NodeJS Sequelize Unknown column false in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm getting an Unknown column false in 'field list' When trying to create the instance `db.Partner.create` .

The code was working, but somehow it stopped (after I input user model and some middleware)

Here is the err I recieve:

```
C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:79
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'false' in 'field list'
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:52:14)
    at Query.ErrorPacket (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:77:18)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:280:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:75:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Connection.query (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:208:25)
    at Query.module.exports.Query.run (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\query.js:26:17)
    at ConnectorManager.execQueueItem (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connector-manager.js:368:21)
    at C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connector-manager.js:326:25
    at C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:278:11
    at ConnectorManager.connect (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connector-manager.js:295:5)
    at Object.create (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\mysql\connector-manager.js:125:19)
    at createResource (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:258:13)
    at dispense (C:\Users\User\code\project\node_modules\generic-pool\lib\generic-pool.js:250:9)
```

Here is my controller:

```
var db = require('../models');

module.exports.addPartner = function(req_title, req_img){
    var partner = db.Partner.create({
        title: req_title,
        img: req_img
    });
}
```

My model:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    var Partner = sequelize.define('Partner', {
        id: {
          type: DataTypes.INTEGER(12),
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
          autoIncrement: true
        },
        title: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false
        },
        img: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
          set: function(val) {
            return this.setDataValue('img', val.toLowerCase());
          }
        }
      }, {
        tableName: 'partner',
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: false
      });

    return Partner;
};
```

my index.js in models folder:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var config = require('../../config/mysql');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var lodash = require('lodash');
var db = {};

// mysql connect
var sequelize = new Sequelize(
  config.database,
  config.user,
  config.password, 
  {
    host: config.host,
    port: config.port,
    logging: false,
    dialect: 'mysql'
  }
 );

fs.readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => (file.indexOf('.') !== 0 && file !== 'index.js'))
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize.import(path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].options.hasOwnProperty('associate')) {
    db[modelName].options.associate(db)
  }
});

module.exports = lodash.extend({
  sequelize,
  Sequelize
}, db);
```

Comment: are this all the models in your code

Comment: @Keval Gohil Yes, finally working:) I took out all other models from "model" folder. After that I had er_no_default_for_field field 'title' doesn't have a default value - it's ok, changed allowNull: for 'title' and 'img' to true.
After that added all other models and everything started to work again))